# How do I install a Linux build runner for bitbucket using rust?

Tags: linux, rust, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have a CI server in an AWS cloud which hosts out BitBucket.

The runners are on a separate EC2 instance.

The code we are using is Rust.

I installed the runners on a windows EC2 and everything is fine.

I follow the instructions to install the runners on a Linux machine (Ubuntu) and the runners cannot find Cargo.

When I connect to the machine I can run it manually from any directory so it should be viewable by the build runner.

Has anyone come across this issue?  I read that I might need to specific the bitness of the system when I install Rust but that did not seem to help :-(

Edit:

I have added the location of Cargo to /etc/environment and to the PATH variable in case the runner could not see it but that has not helped.

Comment: ~~Which CI system is this? Most CIs I know don't run the code directly on the runner but instead encapsulate the checked-out code inside a virtual container. In these cases it would be the responsibility of the (usually Docker) image that's being used to provide Rust & Cargo.~~
Nevermind, just realized that Bitbucket has its own built-in CI; only knew it as a VCS UI so far... couldn't find any reference to its container configuration on the quick.

Comment: can you show your environment file ? https://askubuntu.com/a/24944/1150615